# QT5: undefined reference to `QString::free(QString::Data*)'

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I was trying to compile an old Qt project and the linking stage failed with

```
undefined reference to `QString::free(QString::Data*)'
```

This is a qt4 method, and should not be referenced at all (I'm compiling everything under qt5)

Comment: If you have a question that you want to answer yourself, then please write it as a proper question and answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a bunch of debugging to figure out the issue; documenting it here in the hope that the next person gets a google hit. What was wrong was that I did a git pull and tried compiling at head, but neither make clean nor make distclean removed everything in the release/ directory and the linker was trying to link against some older artefact. (I'm not sure why this exact error, but as best as I can tell QString::free(QString::Data*) is a qt4 method and does not exist in qt5.)

Anyway, if that's the single linker error you're getting, just clean everything out and try again.